# How to spot if model is zero inflated?

Tags: r, regression, zero-inflation

I'm running a linear regression. The response variable is a proportion, and has quite a lot of zeros. The predictor variable is normal distributed.

My two variables look something like these:

```
set.seed(50)
y <- sample(c(rep(0, 20), seq(0, 1, by=0.01)), 100)
set.seed(50)
x <- rnorm(100)
```

And my model looks something like this:

```
summary(lm(y ~ x))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.42550 -0.31907 -0.02064  0.29710  0.59214 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.410990   0.033378  12.313   <2e-16 ***
x           -0.006252   0.033574  -0.186    0.853    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3316 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0003537, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.009847 
F-statistic: 0.03468 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.8527
```

Is there a statistic that will indicate if the model is zero inflated?

Comment: As far as a pure statistical answer goes, I don't think this makes sense.  If your response variable has *any* repeated values, then it must not really be Normally distributed (since the Normal distribution is continuous) ... if the response is a proportion, should you be fitting a binomial GLM instead?  (Or possibly a Beta regression?)

Comment: More information added to question. Note predictor is normal distributed, not response variable.

Comment: @luciano I think the issue is that linear regression, while admittedly frequently used to model proportion data, often doesn't work well in this setting and will not work well with your data. A model for proportional data would be better. `BEINF` from `gamlls` has been mentioned on this site before in the setting of proportion data that includes 0 and 1.

Comment: Your *model* is whatever your model is. The data may have substantially more zeroes than some particular model, but may be perfectly in accord with some other model. e.g. data might have 'too many zeroes' for a Poisson model (suggesting zero-inflation), but might fit a negative binomial without zero inflation.

Answer (score 1):

Combining a couple of comments and adding some more.

First, you have used OLS regression. As Glen notes, that *model* is not zero inflated. Your data may have too many zeros for that model, or not.

Second, your dependent variable is bounded by 0 and 1. As Ben notes, that argues against using OLS regression. Binomial regression or beta regression could be good (although requires that the DV be within 0 and 1, and you have both 0s and 1s. You might get away with adjust those to 0.01 and 0.99).

Third, you have generated data where the variables are not related at all. Saying that your data looks like this. Well, if your data looks like that, there's not much point in any regression. Showing (even after all this time) what your data really look like might help.